# Laravel File Upload & Move. Why Does This Work?

Tags: file-upload, laravel-4, eloquent

http://laravel.io/forum/03-07-2014-file-not-found-after-file-upload

I posted the above and received a prompt solution however I don't understand the solution.  All that I did was reorder the *$file->move($dest)* line.

It would seem that the Eloquent ORM and file uploads are linked somehow?

Answer (score 0):

When you executed:

```
$file->move($dest);
```

Your file moved from one place to another, then this instruction:

```
$file->getMimeType()
```

Which uses `MimeTypeGuesser.php`, was not able to find the old file to read and guess the mime type. So, one solution was to guess before move, as you did, another one is simply:

```
$file = $file->move($dest);
```

Because this move method returns a new object pointing to your new file.